# How do I integration test my types when using ASP.NET Core 6.0

Tags: testing, dependency-injection, nunit, asp.net-core-6.0

Back in the .NET Framework days, when I developed ASP.NET MVC apps, I would separate out all major concerns into their own projects such as database, domain etc. I would also create a project called IOC where I would place my Ninject IOC container with all my types injected. This made accessing the container easy from an NUnit Integration Test project.

However, using .NET 6.0, dependency injection is done in the `Program.cs` file of the web app.

Is it possible to implement a strategy like the one I describe above where I can separate out my dependency injection into a project, and access it from my integration tests? I don't wish to use `WebApplicationFactory` or any such thing. I simply want to be able to integration test my own types such as `IRepository`, `IService1`, `IService2` etc.

Creating these manually for a test is painful as they each have dependencies such as `IMapper`, `IAppLogger`, ... etc etc

Also, it would be nice to test the IOC container itself to make sure it can build and has all necessary dependencies.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has put together a pretty great [article on integration testing with .NET 6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-7.0) that talks a bit about using the [Mvc.Testing](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing) package. It truly is pretty comprehensive so I don't want to replicate it here.

For another flavor, you may like Jeremy Miller's [Alba](https://jasperfx.github.io/alba/) which facilitates similar results with a different syntax.

Feel free to follow up with more specifics after you check them out

Comment: I'm trying to avoid the whole WebApplictionFactory thing. IMO we've taken a step backwards when it comes to testing.  Microsoft have deeply embedded the whole IOC concept into the application pipeline.  We used to be able to integration test a given service so easily. Now we have to unhide program.cs to out test project, and then recreate the entire IOC with all of its dependencies just to test one of our services. Ant the whole thing has become complex. Testing one of my services should be simple and I should be able to do it without all that faff IMO.